# Variance of Capacitance

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, potential, capacitance

I'm studying Capacitance as a high school student and I have come across few things which I am puzzled about.

1. I understand that bringing a negatively charged conductor near a positively charged one decreases its potential. We know by definition that capacitance is the charge required to raise a body's potential by 1V. If so, why does decreasing a body's potential increase its capacitance?
2. I have seen in many sources that capacitance does not depend on charge or potential difference. If the ratio of Q and V is always constant, I don't understand why Capacitance increases in the previous case and in other cases such as *earthing of a plate in parallel to another*.

Comment: You may have #1 "backwards".  Capacitance tells you how much charge a device (e.g., parallel plate capacitor) will hold for a given potential difference across its terminals.

Comment: Ditto David’s comment. Also, the potential difference does not determine capacitance, only it’s physical properties do

Comment: Yeh nevermind. I get it now, thank you so much both of you